# XML Writer - Value saved multiple times?

Tags: php, xml

This is my first exercise for XML and PHP combined, so please be gentle here :(
I have got a normform in php, containing field for name, city, zipcode and so on. And everytime the user is finished writing and submits the formular, the values should be stored in the xml file, and shown on the website.
For the first time, this works pretty fine. But if i submit a second set of values, my xml starts to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE addressbook
SYSTEM "addressbook.dtd">
<addressbook>
 <entry>
 <name last="" first=""/>
 <address>
 <street>
  hallo
  hallo
  hallo
 </street>
 <zip>
  hallo
  hallo
  hallo
 </zip>
 <city>
  hallo
  hallo
  hallo
 </city>
 </address>
</entry>
<entry>
 <name last="hallo" first="hallo"/>
 <address>
 <street>hallo</street>
 <zip>hallo</zip>
 <city>hallo</city>
 </address>
</entry>
```

But actually every xml-entry fragment should look like the lower one, and the values should not be added in a multiplied way in there?
These are my code fragments for writing and reading the xml:

```
public function loadXMLFile(string $filename): array
{
    $data = [];

    if (file_exists($filename) && filesize($filename) != 0) {

        $XML_reader = new XMLReader();
        $XML_reader->open($filename, "UTF-8");
        $entry = null;
        $i = 0;

        while ($XML_reader->read()) {
            switch ($XML_reader->nodeType) {

                case XMLReader::ELEMENT:
                    switch ($XML_reader->name) {

                        case "addressbook":
                            $data = [];
                            break;

                        case "entry":
                            $data[$i] = null;
                            break;

                        case "name":
                            $data[$i]["lastName"] = $XML_reader->getAttribute("lastName");
                            $data[$i]["firstName"] = $XML_reader->getAttribute("firstName");
                            break;

                        case "address":
                            $data[$i]["city"] = $XML_reader->readString();
                            $data[$i]["zip"] = $XML_reader->readString();
                            $data[$i]["street"] = $XML_reader->readString();
                            break;
                    }

                    break;

                case XMLReader::END_ELEMENT:

                    if ($XML_reader->name === "entry") {
                        $i++;
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }

        $XML_reader->close();

    }

    return $data;

}


public function storeXMLValuesFromNormForm(string $filename, array $data): bool
{

    $filename = dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]) . "/" . $filename;

    $XML_Writer = new XMLWriter();
    $XML_Writer->openUri($filename);
    $XML_Writer->setIndent(true);

    $XML_Writer->startDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
    $XML_Writer->writeDtd("addressbook", null, "addressbook.dtd");

    $XML_Writer->startElement("addressbook");

    foreach ($data as $value) {

        $XML_Writer->startElement("entry");

        $XML_Writer->startElement("name");
        $XML_Writer->writeAttribute("last", $value['lastName']);
        $XML_Writer->writeAttribute("first", $value['firstName']);
        $XML_Writer->endElement();

        $XML_Writer->startElement("address");
        $XML_Writer->writeElement("street", $value['street']);
        $XML_Writer->writeElement("zip", $value['zip']);
        $XML_Writer->writeElement("city", $value['city']);
        $XML_Writer->endElement();

        $XML_Writer->endElement();

    }

    $XML_Writer->endElement();
    $XML_Writer->endDocument();
    $XML_Writer->flush();

    return true;

}
```

It would be amazing if somebody could help me. I really dont know what causes this multiplication of the value at that point. **Another important thing to know**: If i outcomment the `loadXMLFile` Function, then the writer writes the XML Part like it should - but only once. The values are then overwritten everytime the formular gets submitted. This does not happen when the method is activated, but well, then the values get somehow multiplied.

Please, help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your finding the address element...

```
 <address>
    <street>hallo</street>
    <zip>hallo</zip>
    <city>hallo</city>
 </address>
```

your doing the following:

```
case "address":
                            $data[$i]["city"] = $XML_reader->readString();
                            $data[$i]["zip"] = $XML_reader->readString();
                            $data[$i]["street"] = $XML_reader->readString();
                            break;
```

BUT - you have only found the address element, and in XML the value of the text at this point is the text of all of the sub-elements as well.
You can only use the values for the elements 'city' etc. once the XML parser has read those elements.  So instead if you store the values of these elements as you find them

```
case "city":
    $city = $XML_reader->readString();
```

And then when you get the *end element* of address, you can store these values into your array.

Comment: thanks a lot that is now working!! but i have another question here as well - last = "" and first = "" - how can i get that away? the values are simply not stored in there :(

Comment: Your using the wrong attribute names, they are 'last' and 'first', your accessing attributes 'lastName' and 'firstName'

Comment: Changed it, now i am getting an undefined index error... sigh :(
when it comes to these two code lines:
`$XML_Writer->writeAttribute("last", $value['last']); 
$XML_Writer->writeAttribute("first", $value['first']);`

Comment: Did you store them in `$data[$i]["lastName"]` or `$data[$i]["last"]` it would be good to make sure that you always use consistent names, so try and use "last" all the way through.

Comment: i did, it works now, thank you so much for all your help!! :)